# How can I access to string with byte?

Tags: python, string

I have a string containing multilingual letters and special character.

```
str1 = "가나42hello world 門()&*&#  [1]"
```

In above string, "가", "나", "門" are 2 bytes, and the rest are 1 byte.

Under these circumstances, is there any way to get the character 'h', which is corresponding to 7th byte of that string? (not `str[7]`, `'l'`)

I mean, Can I do random access using *byte_index*?

I use Python.

Comment: You need to specify the encoding. Otherwise, you will not be able to access the bytes the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python (assuming Python 3) are sequences of characters (where e.g. 한 is one *character*).

They can be represented in memory using different [encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), which represent each character using one or more bytes. Not all encodings can represent all characters, not all encodings require the same amount of bytes.

Assuming [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), let's encode the string and inspect bytes:

```py
s = "가나42hello world 門()&*&# [1]"
b = s.encode("utf-8")
print(b[8])
# This prints 104, the UTF-8 code for 'h'
print(chr(b[8]))
# This prints 'h'
print(b[0:3].decode("utf-8"))
# This prints '가'
```

Note that in UTF-8, each Hangul character takes 3 bytes, not 2, so I've adjusted the indices. If you want the default encoding, omit the parameter to `encode` and `decode`. If you want to find out which encoding you are using, check `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

Comment: I totally agree with @alani Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps dependent on your encoding (when I decode that string using utf-8, the special characters are 3 bytes instead of 2 bytes), but in general you can do this by converting to bytes, performing your selection, and then converting back. For example, the following will print 'h':

```
s = "가나42hello world 門()&*&# [1]"
b = bytes(s, encoding="utf-8")
selection = b[8:9].decode("utf-8")
print(selection)
```

It is important that the slice operation on `b` is a slice and not a single index selection (e.g. using 8:9 to get the 8th byte).